# Playing Video in JavaFX8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX and Im currently working with an application that plays a video(.MP4) at the beginning of the application, however, I cant seem to make it work! Please tell me what's wrong with my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class NoConnection {

    private StackPane root;

    public NoConnection(){
        Media media = null;
        try{
            File video = new File("video.mp4");
            String url = video.toURI().toURL().toString();
            System.out.println("URL: "+url);
            media = new Media(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        player.play();
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

        root = new StackPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color : white;");
        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
    }

    public StackPane getLayout(){
        return root;
    }

}
```

By the way, Im running Windows XP!

Here's the complete error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/11461388.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/31501478.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/29531133.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does the `File` exist? Did you try `video.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()`? Which Java / JavaFX Version are you using?

Comment: Of course!! It exists!

Comment: So you did try `video.exists()`? Just making sure..

Comment: video.exists() return true.

Comment: Is this an OS issue, Im currently using Windows XP.

Comment: What about my other two questions?

Comment: Yes, I also tried video.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm(), but it didnt worked.

Comment: What do you mean by version? jdk? JDK 1.8 update 20

Comment: Ok and what exactly is not working? Any errors?

Comment: There were no errors!... What do you think is the problem? Is it the Operating System? Can I run JavaFX8 in Windows XP?

Comment: Please slow down, take your time and explain your problem.. You still have not expressed what is not working. And yes: Officially Oracle does no longer support WindowsXP since Java 8.

Comment: Oh men, you're right, there is an error: NullPointerException... But all the variables were initialized... Have I missed something?

Comment: And you could help us help you by making an edit to your post with the full stacktrace of that Exception.

Comment: I guess the problem is that File uses the filename from the context root and you got the video in some package. Hence the file isn't found.

Comment: @eckig, please see the error above.

Comment: Well, the stacktrace you posted has nothing to do with the class you posted.. did you actually take a look at it?

Comment: I followed Roland's code below, I created a new project, I got the same error, please see Rolands code below!

Comment: @eckig, I fixed the java.lang.NullPointerException, this time, no errors but unfortunately the video is not appearing!!! Please help!!!

Comment: By the way, the video was 250mb in size.. Is it okay?

Comment: It worked in Windows 7! not in XP!

Comment: That means, there is nothing wrong with my code above!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer:

The FLV container is supported by the media stack on the platforms supported by the JavaFX SDK. A single movie encoded in this format works seamlessly on supported platforms. Standard FLV MIME settings are required on the server side to enable media streaming.

**The MPEG-4 multimedia container is also supported on all operating systems supported by the JavaFX SDK. On the Mac OS X and Windows 7 platforms, playback will be functional without requiring additional software. However, the Linux operating system and versions of Windows older than Windows 7 require the installation of readily available third party software packages, as documented in the JavaFX System Requirements. AAC and H.264/AVC decoding have certain platform-dependent limitations, as described in the JavaFX Release Notes.**

Decoding of some audio and video compression types relies on operating system-specific media engines. The JavaFX media framework does not attempt to handle all multimedia container formats and media encodings supported by these native engines. Instead, the framework attempts to provide equivalent and well-tested functionality across all platforms on which JavaFX is supported.

Answer (score 7):

This is all there is to do: Create a java class with this code:

```
public class VideoTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer( new Media(getClass().getResource("video.mp4").toExternalForm()));
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

        root.getChildren().add( mediaView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        player.play();

    }

}
```

and put the video.mp4 into the same folder. Start it. The video should play.

Btw I got a file not found exception using your code. And Windows XP isn't supported anymore. Neither by Oracle nor by Microsoft. If this simple code doesn't work, you got another problem.

Comment: There is an error! java.lang.NullPointerException, please see the updated code above!

Comment: I created a new project and I followed your code!!! The code above is not the same project...

Comment: I fixed the java.lang.NullPointerException, this time, no errors but unfortunately the video is not appearing!!! Please help!!!

Comment: By the way, the video was 250mb in size.. Is it okay?

Comment: Depends on the video. Try another one. You can't e. g. play videos with 60 fps. What was the problem with the NPE?

Comment: What was the problem with the NPE?

Comment: I dont what NPE means. Anyway, It didnt worked in Windows XP...  Video got played when I ran it on Windows 7.

Comment: That means, there is nothing wrong with my code above!!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException with the code above if the path to video is not found, but the code works when you put it in the same drectory as the source.