# Making video player in java

Tags: java, swing, javafx, video-streaming, media-player

There are two classes - MinimalVideoPlayer.java and Streaming.java
MinimalVideoPlayer.java provides an interface and option for selecting a video file to play.
Streaming.java plays a video
Both of these classes work individually but when I try to run the second class from the first class then the first class runs but the start function of second class doesn't.
MinimalVideoPlayer.java

```
package minimal.video.player;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class MinimalVideoPlayer extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public JPanel contentPane;
    public JButton open;
    public String vPath;
    public MinimalVideoPlayer(){
        super("Minimal Video Player");
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(350, 150, 700, 400);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setBounds(350, 150, 700, 400);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("minimal/video/player/icon/open.png"));
        Image i2 = i1.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon i3 = new ImageIcon(i2);
        open = new JButton(i3);
        open.setBounds(300, 120, 100, 100);
        open.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        open.setBorder(null);
        open.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(open);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MinimalVideoPlayer().setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        FileNameExtensionFilter extension = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Only mp4", "mp4");
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(extension);
        int action = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (action != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return;
        }   
        vPath = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
        String path = vPath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        
        Streaming s = new Streaming(path);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

The path of the selected file is being passed from this java class to the constructor of Streaming.java

Streaming.java

```
package minimal.video.player;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Streaming extends Application{   
    public String path;
    public Streaming(String path){
        this.path = path;
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {     
        String vPath = path;
        Media media = new Media(new File(vPath).toURI().toString());  
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);  
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);  
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);  
        Group root = new Group();  
        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);  
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400);  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Playing video");  
        primaryStage.show();  
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But the start function does not run. What is the problem? How to solve?

Comment: ***Why* is this GUI mixing Swing and Java-FX?** Note that doing so requires special handling for the two threads.

Comment: @AndrewThompson what can be done from here?

Comment: *"what can be done from here?"* Start with: *answer* the question I asked. It is not rhetorical.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have recently learned swing and I wanted to play the video with that. so I found code for playing video using Application class.. So tried to make them work together

Comment: It will be a lot less steep a learning curve to start this all again in pure Java-FX. I'm not familiar with Java-FX (beyond some very newbie basics) so am unable to help with that, further I will not be trying to help with a mixed Swing / Java-FX project.

Comment: *"It will be a lot less steep a learning curve to start this all again in pure Java-FX."* Start with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29071373/418556). Hard code the file name to play, then call `new MediaPlayer(new Media(file.toURI().toString()));`. Once you see that working, proceed from there to open a Java-FX file chooser. Trust me, it will make life a lot less painful.